# Why I can't modify the pointer value?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

So I'm familiar with this code to modify an array, call it `arr` within a function:

```c
void foo(int *arr) {
    arr[0] = 3;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    foo(arr);
    printf("new value: %d\n", arr[0]); // prints 3
}
```

But now suppose I have a pointer in `main` that I want to behave as an array.

```c
int main() {
    int *p;
}
```

In my function `foo`, now I allocate **no** integers to be stored in `p` and change their value or anything to change the initial array.

```c
void foo(int *arr, int no) {
    arr = (int *)malloc(no * sizeof(*arr));
    // some code to change the array
    arr[0] = 1;
}
```

Now if I will call the `foo` function with some random value and try after to print the first element of the array I get a blank screen, and I don't understand why.

In the function I change the pointer's reference to a dynamic allocated array, so there are no problem.

The easiest fix was to return the array, rather than passing it as a pointer.

```c
int *foo(int no) {
    arr = (int *)malloc(no * sizeof(*arr));
    // some code to change the array
    arr[0] = 1;

    return arr;
}
```

Also in the `main` function, I would simply `int* p = foo(10);` and that's the easiest fix.

I want to understand why passing the pointer won't print anything.

Comment: Your first version doesn't change the `arr` defined in `main`, only the one local to `foo`, so `main` only knows about the original value of `arr` ( in particular, it doesn't know where the array you allocated is).

Comment: it does change the array in the main

Comment: @will: I think Scott meant the first `malloc` example, where it allocates a new array and has no means of passing the information back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to `arr` (`arr = ...`) have the same problem as assignment to any argument. For example you would not expect an assignment to `no` (e.g. `no = 5;`) to work in the function?

To be able to modify any data in a function, the function needs a pointer to the data. If you want to modify a pointer then you need a pointer to the pointer:

```
void foo(int **parr)
{
    *parr = malloc(...);
}
```

And you need to use the pointer-to operator to pass it:

```
int *arr;
foo(&arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `foo` defined as:

```
void foo(int *arr, int no) {
    arr = (int *)malloc(no * sizeof(*arr));
    // some code to change the array
    arr[0] = 1;
}
```

allocates an array and initializes its first element, but the caller variable `p` passed to `foo` as `foo(p)` is not modified, only the local argument `arg` gets updated and its final value is lost when the function returns, causing the allocated memory to be unaccessible (*a memory leak*).

Passing the uninitliazed value of the pointer `p` to `foo` is meaningless (actually it has undefined behavior), You must instead return the allocated pointer in `foo` and store this return value to the local variable in `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int no) {
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(no * sizeof(*arr));
    // some code to change the array
    if (arr != NULL) {
        arr[0] = 1;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(void) {
    int *arr = foo(2);
    if (arr != NULL)
        printf("new value: %d\n", arr[0]); // prints 1
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why it is meaningless? doesn't the function foo receives a pointer and simply changes its pointed adress?

Comment: @will: If you receive an `int` from the caller, and change the value received, does the caller's `int` change? Same thing for pointers, if you receive a pointer, and change the pointer itself (not what it points to), the caller's pointer remains unchanged.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes: in C almost everything is passed by value, including pointers. The only exception is arrays that are passed as a pointer to their first element.  This process is referred to as *arrays decay into a pointer to their first element when used in an expression context except as an argument to `sizeof` and `alignof`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: this is not true in c++, where passing by reference is allowed and determined by the function definition, which is not always easy to determine at the call site because of overloading.